# Get database records which are within a specific timeframe

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's assume I have the following table called `video_data`. I have another one `videos` which isn't really relevant though. I use it to query videos for a specific channel, but that wouldn't change the query. It's just to get the calculations for one channel instead of all.

```
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
| id | video_id | views |     created_at      |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |        1 |  1000 | 2016-04-26 00:00:00 |
|  2 |        2 |   500 | 2016-04-26 00:00:01 |
|  3 |        3 |  2500 | 2016-04-26 00:00:02 |

|  4 |        1 |  1500 | 2016-04-26 02:00:00 |
|  5 |        2 |  1000 | 2016-04-26 02:00:01 |
|  6 |        3 |  3000 | 2016-04-26 02:00:02 |

|  7 |        1 |  5000 | 2016-04-26 04:00:00 |
|  8 |        2 | 10000 | 2016-04-26 04:00:01 |
|  9 |        3 | 30000 | 2016-04-26 04:00:02 |
+----+----------+-------+---------------------+
```

What I want to do now is to get the average value of views inside a time frame. Let's say, I want to get the average views a video has within 2 hours. Let's do this with the video with the `video_ 1` as an example

So what I would need to do would be the following. I would need to get the average value of  `id: 1` and `id: 4`. This would be `1250` because it's `(1000 + 1500) / 2`. Next I would need to get the average of `id: 4` and `id: 7`. This would be `3250` because it's `(1500 + 5000) / 2`. Now the average the video gets in two hours would be `2250` because it's `(1250 + 3250) / 2`, correct?

Now what I have no idea, is how to get this from MySQL. Is it even possible to do in plain MySQL? I need this for many, many video_data. Like I have data for over 100 hours! And if the data with `id: 100` and `id: 105` are less than two hours apart from each other I would still need this data to be also calculated for the calculation.

I wanted to do it somehow like this

```
select *
from `video_data`
where `video_id` in (select `id` from `videos` where `channel_id` = 1)
  and TIMEDIFF(`created_at`, `created_at`) < '02:00:00'
```

but this simply returns me every result because the result of `TIMEDIFF` is always `00:00:00`

I created an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f8ae8/0) for this

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `video_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `shares` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `video_data` (`id`, `video_id`, `shares`, `likes`, `comments`, `total_count`, `created_at`, `updated_at`)
VALUES
    (1889612, 245721, 777, 69922, 1314, 72013, '2015-10-04 20:00:04', '2015-10-04 20:00:04'),
    (1896986, 245721, 970, 90611, 1570, 93151, '2015-10-04 21:00:04', '2015-10-04 21:00:04'),
    (1904145, 245721, 1121, 104636, 1725, 107482, '2015-10-04 22:00:05', '2015-10-04 22:00:05'),
    (1911872, 245721, 1199, 115389, 1838, 118426, '2015-10-04 23:00:04', '2015-10-04 23:00:04'),
    (1882621, 245007, 1651, 102569, 2659, 106879, '2015-10-04 19:00:06', '2015-10-04 19:00:06'),
    (1889613, 245007, 1769, 113910, 2775, 118454, '2015-10-04 20:00:05', '2015-10-04 20:00:05'),
    (1896988, 245007, 1829, 121646, 2851, 126326, '2015-10-04 21:00:05', '2015-10-04 21:00:05'),
    (1904150, 245007, 1889, 127677, 2917, 132483, '2015-10-04 22:00:06', '2015-10-04 22:00:06'),
    (1911877, 245007, 1914, 132764, 2957, 137635, '2015-10-04 23:00:05', '2015-10-04 23:00:05'),
    (1845984, 239950, 675, 75030, 1373, 77078, '2015-10-04 12:00:04', '2015-10-04 12:00:04'),
    (1849749, 239950, 857, 97028, 1617, 99502, '2015-10-04 13:00:05', '2015-10-04 13:00:05'),
    (1853996, 239950, 1021, 113648, 1801, 116470, '2015-10-04 14:00:04', '2015-10-04 14:00:04'),
    (1858726, 239950, 1148, 126624, 1919, 129691, '2015-10-04 15:00:04', '2015-10-04 15:00:04'),
    (1863954, 239950, 1297, 137950, 2019, 141266, '2015-10-04 16:00:04', '2015-10-04 16:00:04'),
    (1869723, 239950, 1427, 148069, 2102, 151598, '2015-10-04 17:00:04', '2015-10-04 17:00:04'),
    (1875982, 239950, 1549, 156391, 2194, 160134, '2015-10-04 18:00:05', '2015-10-04 18:00:05'),
    (1882622, 239950, 1618, 161312, 2232, 165162, '2015-10-04 19:00:07', '2015-10-04 19:00:07'),
    (1889616, 239950, 1683, 164783, 2261, 168727, '2015-10-04 20:00:06', '2015-10-04 20:00:06'),
    (1896990, 239950, 1722, 167718, 2278, 171718, '2015-10-04 21:00:06', '2015-10-04 21:00:06'),
    (1904151, 239950, 1743, 170240, 2290, 174273, '2015-10-04 22:00:07', '2015-10-04 22:00:07'),
    (1911880, 239950, 1761, 172363, 2300, 176424, '2015-10-04 23:00:06', '2015-10-04 23:00:06');
```

When I now execute the query

```
select avg(pd.shares) AS shares, avg(pd.likes) AS likes, avg(pd.comments) AS comments FROM video_data pd JOIN video_data pd1 ON pd1.video_id = pd.`video_id` AND TIMEDIFF(pd.created_at, pd1.created_at) <= '02:00:00';

+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|  shares   |    likes    | comments  |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| 1298.2077 | 123542.5769 | 2032.2769 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
```

But when going over the results it looks like the `likes` value is the average of **ALL** likes in the database, and not only the ones who are only 2 hours apart from each other, right? Or is it correct?

Comment: "correct?" How would we know?

Comment: id 4 and id 7 appear to be for the same video at the same date, so I'm puzzled as to why these would be separate rows.

Comment: There is no channel_id, and no clear explanation of how the timeframe is defined.

Comment: I added an explaination

Comment: Still no channel_id. It's very confusing.

Comment: From what value you want the two hour difference?Let's say that you have values-00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00,all related to one single `video_id`. 00:00 and 02:00 are 2 hours apart from each other. Now 01:00, which falls into the range, is 2 hours apart from 03:00. Should 03:00 be also counted in then, or not? If not, how do you determine, that you will no longer count with 01:00,(because it has already been counted) when you reach the 03:00? For me, it sounds like you need to think about what you want to achieve at all. From what I know now, I would use temporary table and pretty complex cursor

Comment: Hey, yes that would also be counted in. I want to get the average value of views a video has in a time frame of 2 hours. But not just the last 2 hours, all 2 hour statistics ever existed

Comment: I see, but there must be some starting point... I still don't understand if you provide "some" time as an input and you want to relate the statistics to that input, or the time that the 2 hours will be deducted from, comes from each value in the `created_at` column (for respective `video_id`). i.e. user provides an input time and application displays statistics for last 2 hours from the choosen time, or the application should "know" the statistics related to every possible time in the `created_at` column?

Comment: Hey. It's kinda the same. The user provides an input time like 3 hours or 6 hours, etc. But I want to save this data in a separate database table so the data will be *cached* and doesn't need to load from the database all the time again.

Comment: In that case, I would try to create a cursor for `select id, video_id, views, created_at from video_data order by video_id,created_at` that, for each combination of video_id and created_at, will find every id, that falls into the  two hour range, and store it into separate table. Then you will have all IDs in needed range and can use them to count the average views etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*,avg(t1.views) from videos t join videos t1 on
t1.video_id=t.video_id 
and timediff(t.created_at,t1.created_at)< '02:00:00' 
group by t.video_id
```

try this query it should work

Comment: Typo: `created_at` not `crated_at`

Comment: will change it @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: Give me a second please, I'll try to check if that returns the correct values

Comment: This is definitely missing a crucial piece of information

Comment: @Musterknabe i've added a group by clause see if this works for you,it will group the values and give results for specific video_id's

Comment: I have done this already, but the problem is, that when I do that I'm getting 3 results instead of one. Or would I need to take these three values and again sum them and divide by 3?

Answer (score 0):

> but this simply returns me every result because the result of TIMEDIFF is always 00:00:00

It does so becauase you used the same column:

```
TIMEDIFF(`created_at`, `created_at`)
```

so it's hardly possible to make it produce different result. You perhaps wanted to use `NOW()` as one of the arguments?

Comment: I understood that. It was just an example how I tried to get the result but failed. `NOW()` wouldn't work though, because the the video_data could be 10 and 12 hours old and would still need to be calculated since these two datas have a 2 hours time difference.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski you are absolutely right, but aren't answering the question